# Are "parent"/"child" in hierarchies technical terms? What's a non-technical version?

Tags: terminology, computing

I want to display some hierarchical data. In math and computer science we'd use "parent" and "children", but I'm unsure if they're considered technical terms. Are there similar words that would be understood by nearly all English speakers?

Edit:

The specific context is communities that belong to other communities. E.g. the soccer community would be a subset/child of the sports community and the opposite would be the superset/parent.

Comment: You do not give the nature of the data; you do not say in what format the phrase will be used, and you do not say who your target audience are. We cannot guess these things. As a general answer, "If you are using such phrases as "hierarchical data", you will be addressing an audience who are quite familiar with "parent and **child**" relationships."

Comment: The target audience is all English speakers. I edited the question

Comment: **1** You do not give the nature of the data;  - **What is the subject of the data?** **2** you do not say in what format the phrase will be used - **Is it column headers, description of a graph, within the text?** and **3** you do not say who your target audience are - **All English speakers** is not a "target audience" - **Who will be most interested in this?**

Comment: Mathematics will look at a hierarchical graph and call the all the circles *nodes* and all the attaching lines *edges*. The top-most node is called the *root* node. The bottom-most nodes are called *leaf* nodes. A node that is above and attached to another node is called a parent. I've seen the *parent/child* named for Object-Oriented (computer science) classes as well. I'd say it's widespread enough to be used in many contexts. For communities, you could say that the NFL is the *parent* organization of the AFC and the NFC.

Comment: Subcommunity might work, but not supercommunity. The soccer community is a subcommunity of the sporting community, but I don't know a noun to say the sporting community includes the soccer community. Parent organisation implies an organisational hierarchy, not a community hierarchy. I am not sure about parent community -it seems to me to be more about history than corrent relationships.

Comment: What wrong with **subset**, as used in the question? (It's so-call opposite is not *superset*, but just **set**.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Where C is a subset of P, the way to express this relationship the other way around is indeed that P is a superset of C. "Set" won't do in that context.

Answer (score -1):

You could call your top level categories **superordinates** and the second-level subcategories **subordinates** (in this context, the natural antonym to **superordinates**). From Lexico:

> **[superordinate](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/superordinate)**: A thing that represents a superior order or category within a system of classification.

In your example, *sports community* would be the **superordinate** and soccer community, basketball community, etc. would be **subordinates**.

From an ELU perspective, you might be interested in the terms **hypernym** and **hyponym**. Again from Lexico:

> **[hypernym](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hypernym)**: A word with a broad meaning that more specific words fall under; a superordinate. For example, color is a hypernym of red.

> **[hyponym](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hyponym)**: A word of more specific meaning than a general or **superordinate** term applicable to it; contrasted with **hypernym**. For example, spoon is a hyponym of cutlery.